# Segmentation fault error with trig functions in C

Tags: c

I am trying to add the ability to have sin, pow, and exp function capability to my calculator.
I am getting 'segmentation fault" when I try and compile.
I believe the problem lies in the 'void trigFunction(char s[])' function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'
#define TRIG 1 /**/
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
void swap(void);
void trigFunction(char s[]);

main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    printf("\nEnter numbers below in the following format\nwith a space between each:\n");
    printf("\tnum1 num2 operator\n");
    printf("You may use the operators:\n");
    printf("plus(+), minus(!), divide(/), multiply(*),\npercentage(%), swap(~), sine(S), exp(E), and pow(P)\n");

    while((type = getop(s)) != EOF)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            /*other cases I have taken out to make code shorter*/

            case TRIG: /*case for sin, exp, pow functions*/
                trigFunction(s);
                break;


            case '\n':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());/*prints out soultion*/
                break;
            default:
                printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void trigFunction(char s[])
{
    double op2;

    if(0 == strcmp(s, 'S'))/*strcmp() function compares the string pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by s2.*/
        push(sin(pop()));/*pushes the sine of pop() onto the stack*/
    else if(0 == strcmp(s, "E"))
        push(exp(pop()));
    else if(0 == strcmp(s, "P"))
    {   
        op2 = pop();
        push(pow(pop(), op2));
    }   
    else
        printf("I don't know what you mean by %s, but I may \nself destruct if you don't enter         \na correct operator\n", s);
}

#define MAXVAL 100

int sp = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];

void push (double f)
{
    if(sp < MAXVAL)
    {
        val[sp++] = f;
    }   
    else
    {
        printf("error: stack full, cant push %g\n",f);
    }   
}

double pop(void)
{
    if(sp > 0)
    {
        return val[--sp];
    }   
    else
    {
        printf("error: stack empty \n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int getop(char s[])
{
  int i = 0, c, next;

  while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')/*skips white space*/
    ;
  s[1] = '\0';

  if(isalpha(c))
   {
      i = 0;
      while(isalpha(s[i++] = c ))
         c = getch();     
      s[i - 1] = '\0';
      if(c != EOF)
         /*ungetch(c);*/
      return TRIG;
   }

  if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.' && c != '-')/* not number. may contain minus*/
    return c; 
  if(c == '-')
  {
    next = getch();
    if(!isdigit(next) && next != '.')
    {
        ungetch(next);/*puts next char in buffer*/
        return c;
    }    
    c = next;
  }
  else
    c = getch();

  while(isdigit(s[++i] = c))
            c = getch();
    if(c == '.')                     /* Collect fraction part */
        while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
                        ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);/*puts c in buffer*/
    return NUMBER;
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

int getch(void)
{
    return(bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
    {
        printf("unGetch: too many characters\n");
    }
  else
    {
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger to pinpoint the erroneous instruction. also, change `if(0 == strcmp(s, 'S'))` to `if(0 == strcmp(s, "S"))`. Learn to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try to turn warnings on in the compiler. The error that Sourav told you about should have been found by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void trigFunction(char s[])
{
    double op2;

    if(0 == strcmp(s, 'S'))/*strcmp() function compares the string pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by s2.*/
        push(sin(pop()));/*pushes the sine of pop() onto the stack*/
    else if(0 == strcmp(s, "E"))
        push(exp(pop()));
    else if(0 == strcmp(s, "P"))
    {   
        op2 = pop();
        push(pow(pop(), op2));
    }   
    else
        printf("I don't know what you mean by %s, but I may \nself destruct if you don't enter         \na correct operator\n", s);
}
```

Well, lets take a look:

```
if(0 == strcmp(s, 'S'))
```

should be

```
if(0 == strcmp(s, "S"))
```

as you're passing a single `char` into a function expecting a `char *`...

This should fix your code.

You could probably simplify it further though.  In all cases you are only looking at the first character, so you could just do:

```
if (s[0] = 'S')
```

and compare a `char` to a `char`, although this won't help if you want to expand it later, e.g. using `as` for `arcsine`.

*sidenote:

Interesting to know that the main three trig functions are* `sin`, `exp` and `pow`. *I've been doing it wrong for years with* `sin`, `cos` and `tan`.
*(I assume they are just placeholders)*